# Converting Online Express App to an Offline App for distribution

Tags: windows, docker, express

I have been trying to convert my express app with a backend that requires specific dependencies that users need to access to be an offline app on Windows, which is currently distributed online by building a docker image out of it and deploying it to Google Cloud Run.

My plan was to use electron and let the installer force the users to install Docker Desktop since the application requires dependencies that are only available in Ubuntu (and in this way, I only need to use my Docker image to distribute it).

I know that it is a bad idea to let users install Docker. And I am here, after researching for a week, to sincerely ask for your help on what would be the right direction to convert it offline.

Do I really need to refactor my application to be Windows compatible, or is there a way where I can use my existing implementation without using Docker? **

*Edit: Specified that my app has a backend that requires specific dependencies that users need to access. Credits to @super.

Comment: "express app" is a bit vague. It sounds like you have a backend for a web app that requires some specific dependencies? You need that backend to be accessible on the persons local machine?

Comment: Oh, my bad, yes @super. It's mostly backend with a little bit of frontend.

Comment: I forgot to answer your second question @super. Yes, most dependencies are usually compilers like GCC, mono, etc. and it needs to be on the person's local machine in order for the backend to call those compilers and run a specific script.